# Is it possible to highlight ObjC code in Intellij IDEA?

Tags: objective-c, intellij-idea, syntax-highlighting

Intellij IDEA have IDE AppCode for iOS projects on ObjC/Swift.
I am develop crossplatform app (android and ios supports) on Cordova which contain Java, JS and ObjC as base languages. And unforunately IDEA do not highlight ObjC code. I have not found a plugin that would it did.

Is it possible to highlight it? How do you solve this problem? Using multiple IDEs?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this, but it is only syntax highlighting, not auto-complete.
For that I'am afraid you will have to use AppCode or Xcode.

https://github.com/jkaving/intellij-colors-solarized